# passing argument x of 'y' from incompatible pointer type

Tags: c, arrays, file

This is from a program that was written mostly for me to get the hang of fopen and similar syntax before attempting to use it in a larger program. So the only thing the program is trying to accomplish is to open a file (scores.dat), read the data in that file, assign it to an array, and then print the array.

This is the segment of code where I have an error:

```
int scores[13][4];

FILE *score; 
score = fopen("scores.dat", "r");

fscanf("%d %d %d %d", &scores[0][0], &scores[0][1], &scores[0][2], &scores[0][3]);

printf("%d &d %d %d", scores[0][0], scores[0][1], scores[0][2], scores[0][3]);

fclose(score);
```

When compiling, I get the error:

```
text.c: In function 'main':
text.c:15: warning: passing argument 1 of 'fscanf' from incompatible pointer type
text.c:15: warning: passing argument 2 of 'fscanf' from incompatible pointer type
```

How would I fix that?

In case it's important, scores.dat looks like this:

```
88 77 85 91 65 72 84 96 50 76 67 89 70 80 90 99 42 65 66 72 80 82 85 83 90 89 93 
98 86 76 85 99 99 99 99 99 84 72 60 66 50 31 20 10 90 95 91 10 99 91 85 80
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're missing the first argument of `fscanf()`:

```
fscanf(score, "%d %d %d %d", &scores[0][0], ... etc.
       ^^^^^
       this needs to be a `FILE *`, and not `const char *`.
```

Comment: And since `FILE *score;` is a pointer, he will probably need to use :
`fscanf(score, "%d %d %d %d", scores[0][0], ... etc.`

Comment: @MehdiKaramosly Why that? `fscanf()` modifies its arguments. You certainly don't understand how it works (and how pointers work).

Comment: that was a long time that I did not manipulate pointer's addresses... I know that even matrix's elements are put one next to the other in the memory so you can access the addresses by many ways `//scores +i*j*sizeof(int);`

Answer (score 4):

You forgot to mention the file:

```
fscanf(score, "%d %d %d %d", &scores[0][0], ...);
//     ^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1):

Your understanding of `fopen()` is fine as you have used it correctly.But the arguments you have passed for `fscanf()` doesn't match with its prototype.Here's the prototype for that:

```
int fscanf ( FILE *, const char * , ... );
```

So,you should use :

```
fscanf(source,"%d %d %d %d", &scores[0][0], &scores[0][1], &scores[0][2], &scores[0][3]);
```

One more thing about `fopen()`.It's prudent to include some code that displays a message when there is an error opening a file using `fopen()` and then exits the program. Something like:

```
if(source==NULL)
{
 printf("Error opening file");
 exit(1);
}
```